# How to determine if something is an eigenvalue of A without knowing A

Tags: linear-algebra, education

## I'm having trouble with a true/false question on my Linear Algebra homework...

Let *A* be an *n x n* matrix. If dim Nul(*A*-2 *I*) = 3 then λ = 2 is an eigenvalue of *A*.

I know that dim Nul(*A*-2 *I*) = 3 tells me that the dimension of the eigenspace is 3, so the span contains 3 vectors; however, I'm not sure how this connects to λ = 2 being an eigenvalue...I would assume that it is, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Why did you have to start with a bold typeface?

Comment: Hint: You know that there exists a non-zero $x$ such that $(A-\lambda I)x = Ax - \lambda x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It's the definition of eigenvalue. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible. And a matrix is invertible if and only if it has a nontrivial nullspace. If you know that $A-2I$ has a nullspace of dimension 3, then it is not invertible, hence 2 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @StevieWonders you're welcome. If it has answered your question you may wish to accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: @StevieWonders did you delete your comment thanking me? Don't forget to accept an answer